# Sonarqube Update 6.7 to 7.9 - empty tables

Tags: sonarqube

After an update to `Sonar7.9` my all projects, groups and users are missing. Only the default entries exist in the tables. 
Can anyone help?

```
Sonar 7.9 run in a new instanz (another Port)
DB Dump (from active Sonar-6.7-DB) import in a new database
New DB  - REINDEX DATABASE ...
Start new Sonar 7.9 - It runs, with no problems
```

The `page ../setup` informs me that everything is ok.

The original table `(Sonar 6.7)` contains all values.
It looks as if the restart of the new sonar is empty the existing tables, like a new fresh sonar installation.

Guide guide me how to fix it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the solution is to append the correct schema to the DB driver.

sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/db-name?currentSchema=schema_name>

I still don't know why a DB can have multiple schemas?